# Delete a Cell in Excel if it has the same value as any other cell in workbook?

Tags: excel-formula

I have a workbook that has the name of every customer we have sold service to from 2014-2006. Each column has the year of service and the rows contain customer names. What I am trying to do find out the latest year a customer was serviced. Is there a function in excel to delete a cell if it contains the exact same information as a different cell? For instance, if Joe Smith received service in 2014 and 2012, is there a way to delete the cell with Joe Smith in the 2012 column? Except that I need to do it for every single customer and keep only their name in the latest date (that they were serviced) column.

Comment: I don't think a formula will work.  You should post this as an excel-vba question.

Answer (score 0):

The way that I would tackle this is to make new columns for 2014-2006 with a formula referring to the original ones.

Assuming that column `B` has 2014 through to column `J` having 2006, our "working columns" will be `K` (2014) to `S` (2006).

The formula to use in these new cells (example given for `K2`):

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(B2),COUNTA($B2:B2)>1),"",B2)
```

So we are checking two things:

- If the corresponding real column for the year is blank, we will have `""` - coming from `ISBLANK(B2)`
- If there are values in years to the left, we will use `""` - coming from `COUNTA($B2:B2)>1` - this range has an fixed reference to the first year column and a variable reference to the current year's column... for 2006 the range would be `$B2:J2` but the copy-paste of the formula will deal with that. If only our cell has the value then the `COUNTA` will be 1.
- if neither of those conditions a true, we'll use the name in the cell

Once this formula has been copy-pasted to the whole range, you can then copy-paste-values and get rid of those original columns...